# Import data from ebay to google spreadsheet using IMPORTHTML

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to Import a list from:

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=silver+chain&_sacat=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1

to a Google Spreadsheet using `=IMPORTHTML` function, The Formula I was using as below,

A1:

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=silver+chain&_sacat=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1
```

A2:

```
=IMPORTHTML(A1,"list",4)
```

But it returns Incorrect results.
For example:

ebay - `Alloy (34,237)`
google sheets - `Alloy (42,069)`

Can somebody help me, I'm new to google sheet scripting and I'll really grateful if somebody can help me.

waiting to hear from somebody...

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting a discrepancy in results based on your location.

If you are located overseas for example, Ebay may parse the number of results based on sellers who will ship to your region. When the Google server makes the inquiry, it's doing so from a location different than your own, and thus may get a different total.

I run across this from time to time. If you're logged into Ebay you may try changing your shipping address and see what it does to the total results you get.

Comment: TNX. It strange - If I check in the option "sold listings" its happen again